# ZMQ PUB SUB getting stuck after running for a while

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I have a system where there is a single subscriber, subscribed to multiple publishers:

subscriber code

```
sub_socket.bind(zmq.SUB,"address:port1")
sub_socket.bind(zmq.SUB,"address:port2")
sub_socket.bind(zmq.SUB,"address:port3")
```

and publisher code

```
process 1:
    pub_socket1.connect(zmq.PUB,"address:port1")
process 2:
    pub_socket2.connect(zmq.PUB,"address:port2")
process 3:
    pub_socket3.connect(zmq.PUB,"address:port3")
```

process 1 is sending message at 100 msg/sec, process 2 at ~50 msg/sec and process 3 sends message 1 per hour.

I have noticed that after running for a while I see that subscriber gets stuck, i.e. it does not receive message.

If I restart the system, it works as normal.

I am using `PYZMQ 14.7`

Question **1**:

I am using single subscriber and multiple publisher in the manner above. Is it the right way?

Question **2**:

I am aware of **`HWM`** limit, I am not sure if the messages, I am sending can cause that.

Has any one seen such an issue with `pyzmq`?

Comment: You may want to read **whathaveyoutried.com & show some respect** to the StackOverflow Community, which strongly encourages to post high quality questions, altogether with a **MCVE ( a Minimum-Complete-Verifiable-Example of code ) showing what-you-have-tried so far**. You may want to update your post, so as to meet this minimum reasonable level of quality & to show your will to respect other StackOverflow contributing members. They are professionals who love to answer good questions on MCVE-related issues. **Enjoy being StackOverflow Contributing Member & do support this Community Netiquette**

Comment: > You might have already seen moderators, who close questions, that are opinion-based. Try to avoid this. You might try to re-articulate question in such a manner it contains some evidence-based quantitative properties - buffer sizing, zmq-transport class influence on the observed phenomenon and last but not least, post your actual code. That matters most. Your **`.bind()`/`.connect()`** setup is not the most important part. `zmq.SUBSCRIBE`, `.recv()` / `.poll()` + control loop(s) mechanics are. Kindly review / update your post so as to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

### A1: Yes,

`ZeroMQ` supports multiple **`.bind()`**-s. This is not a root issue.

### A2: No,

ZeroMQ shall have no problems with indicated traffic flow. If in doubts, redesign your system so as to have some self-diagnostic monitoring.

> **`process 1`** is sending message at 100 msg/s,
>   **`process 2`** at ~50 msg/s
>   **`process 3`** sends message 1 per hour.

lets you plenty of space for adding a smart self-diagnostics.

Maybe start with a watchdog-timer to detect when exactly the message-flow seems to stop on the observer side and for the `process 3`, **`.close()`** and **`.connect()`** for each message and check which of the incoming message-flows stops to appear visible on the observer side.